# Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing writable

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hadoop2

hive> select * from tweets_text ORDER BY created_time ASC LIMIT 10;

URL:

### http://standbynamenode-zat6kzjl.canopy.com:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1483098353987_0020&tipid=task_1483098353987_0020_m_000000

Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing writable {"tweet_id":814718430955900928,"created_unixtime":1483078985333,"created_time":"Fri Dec 30 06:23:05 +0000 2016","lang":"it","displayname":"VentagliP","time_zone":"Rome","msg":"RT cristinafalasch Mi fa male al cuoreche la virtù non possa viver liberadal morso dell’invidia
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing writable {"tweet_id":814718430955900928,"created_unixtime":1483078985333,"created_time":"Fri Dec 30 06:23:05 +0000 2016","lang":"it","displayname":"VentagliP","time_zone":"Rome","msg":"RT cristinafalasch Mi fa male al cuoreche la virtù non possa viver liberadal morso dell’invidia
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:543)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:163)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: Unterminated string at 272 [character 273 line 1]
        at org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe.onMalformedJson(JsonSerDe.java:412)
        at org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe.deserialize(JsonSerDe.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.readRow(MapOperator.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.access$200(MapOperator.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:534)
        ... 9 more

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 3  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

Answer (score 1):

First check hive-site.xml whether you updated with all the required properties and goto code which is creating issue. The url which is given is not opening for me.